# passing a string variable to a function np.array

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy

there is a string with the given value
`my = "~obr0.isnull(), ~obr1.isnull(), ~obr2.isnull(), ~obr3.isnull(), ~obr4.isnull()"`
this line should be passed to
`itog = np.any(np.array([my]), axis=0)`
so that the interpreter reads it like this
`itog = np.any(np.array([~obr0.isnull(), ~obr1.isnull(), ~obr2.isnull(), ~obr3.isnull(), ~obr4.isnull()]), axis=0)`
during the execution of the code, the variable "my" will be changed and then passed to np.array

tried to do so
`itog = np.any(np.fromstring(my, dtype='uint8'))`
but it throws an error
"DeprecationWarning: The binary mode of fromstring is deprecated, as it behaves surprisingly on unicode inputs. Use frombuffer instead"

tried to do so
`itog = np.any(np.frombuffer(my, dtype='uint8'))`
but it throws an error
"TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'"

Comment: `my` looks like an expression, a piece of code.  It has to `exec` first, producing (I expect) a tuple of boolean values (e.g. `(True, False, False,True`)`)

Comment: Why not `arr = np.array([-x.isnull() for x in [obr0, obr1, ...]])`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
np.any(np.array([eval(s) for s in my.split(',')]), axis=0)
```

will do what you want. It will work for any comma-separated string of statements that return the same type.